# error while trying to use lombok.jar in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, lombok

*I was initially using vs-code where everything was working.*

I think eclipse *doesnt understand* I am using lombok, so I downloaded lombok.jar from [here](https://projectlombok.org/download)

while trying to run `java -jar lombok.jar` i get the following error -

[image]

---

eclipse -

[image]

---

java version and paths

[image]

---

Comment: First, you have two versions of Java that are confusing things - get your PATH to pick one or the other (the `java` command is one version, `javac` another).  Second, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di) - it looks like you need some additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

the issue, as pointed out by [@stdunbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2933977/stdunbar) was conflicting versions

---

i was initially trying

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java 1
```

but it didnt work. what worked was

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

i selected `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java` there, and now it works

Comment: Mine says there is nothing to configure , there is only one alternative, but then also I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that your JAVA_HOME and java -version point to the same Java. For that make sure you have updated JAVA_HOME variable in "/etc/profile" or "/etc/environment" or "~/.bashrc", all these files should be updated if they point to different JAVA folders.